# Using shin/elbow twist bones?

Tags: animation, rigging

I see lots of character rigs have the shin bone split into 2 or even 3 pieces. Why is this done? All I can find is that it has something to do with the ankle? It seems to be a common practice, but does not seem to be done in game rigs.

EDIT: I have found from another source that these are twist bones to deal with distortions from rotating a bone at it's root (in this case, the knee or elbow.) How do I use these correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous answer is wrong.
The reason sometimes you see a bone or sometimes multiple bones in the middle of a limb section such as in between the shoulder and elbow bone, or in between the elbow and wrist bones is for volume preservation during twisting.
Do this:
Stick your arm forward palm down.
Now just turn your palm up but watch your forearm.
You will notice that your entire forearm twists smoothly across its length!
but if you turn your hand to the side or up and down, just the hand turns.
The idea of placing a bone in the middle of the forearm is to separate the twist from the other bone rotations for better skin weight deformations.
the same applies to the upper arm. if you stick your arm out to the side and twist your arm, you will see that your bicep muscle kind of sort of smoothly follows the twist of the arm WHILE the deltoid DOES NOT! so the idea of placing a joint in the middle of the bicep is, again, to separate the twisting from the other two rotations for better skin weight distribution.
If you can get away with more twist bones, the better as they will help preserve volume better than a single bone.
the same applies to the leg.
If you twist your leg, the big leg muscles near your hips will do little twisting and your gluts will do very little.
And same with your calf if you twist your foot HOWEVER the effect is much much smaller there.
If you want more help understanding this, look into the "Cane Toad" rig for Maya. Variations of it are kind of the standard across platforms.
I'm actually trying to find out if it's easy to setup something like this in blender before I decide to switch to it.

Answer (score 2):

Many rigs have two sets of leg and arm bones, one is used for animating with [FK (forwards kinematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_kinematics) and the other for [IK (inverse kinematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics). These rigs will also have a property to choose which one is in effect and use a common bone layer to make it easy to show/hide each set of bones.

Sometimes an extra bone may be placed in the middle of a main bone to allow 'tweaking' the limb. This tweak provides a way to bend the limb, usually for more cartoony effects.

The feet often use several bones that provide multiple pivot points, which make it easy to lift the foot up on the toes or rotate it back on the heel.

Many armatures are custom built for a particular model, the animation planned for that model can influence what the rig is designed to do. Extra bones get added to provide some sort of extra movement that will be unique to that model, some are used for deforming parts of the mesh while others are only used as controllers to make moving other bones easier.

As for games, the less there is to work with the quicker it is to draw on screen, for the same reason that games use low poly models, they can also use simpler armatures to help maintain performance. During game creation a more complex rig can be used, then the simple rig can be calculated and saved for game play.